# Create data with function inside shinyServer to feed ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, shiny

I have a Shiny app what calculates some power estimates for a type of genetic association study. The ui.R is pretty simple, and the server.R has a function that gives a data frame (I think I can't have this function as `reactive` because it has some parameters).

The link to the Gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/aurora-mareviv/5895082). To run it:

```
library(shiny)
shiny:: runGist('5895082')
```

The app calculates correctly the estimates, but I have two questions regarding it:

- Is it possible to have the `output$powTable` actually represent all the values contained within the range, in the first `sliderInput(n.cases)`?. It only seems to represent the two extreme values of the range... what I'm doing wrong?
- There's an error when running the app:

  `Error: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.`

How can I pass the data (reactivity?) from the function `f()` to feed the ggplot? After much trial and error, I am very lost. Where can be the error in my code? Many thaks in advance!

The original code of the function works well: (EDITED)

```
 f <- function(ncases, p0, OR.cas.ctrl, Nh, sig.level) {
num.cases <- ncases
p0 <- p0
Nh <- Nh
OR.cas.ctrl <- OR.cas.ctrl
sig.level <- sig.level
# Parameters related to sig.level, from [Table 2] of Samuels et al.
# For 90% power and alpha = .05, Nscaled = 8.5
    if (sig.level == 0.05){
A <- -28 # Parameter A for alpha=.05
x0 <- 2.6 # Parameter x0 for alpha=.05
d <- 2.4 # Parameter d for alpha=.05
    }
    if (sig.level == 0.01){
A <- -13 # Parameter A for alpha=.01
x0 <- 5 # Parameter x0 for alpha=.01
d <- 2.5 # Parameter d for alpha=.01
    }
    if (sig.level == 0.001){
A <- -7 # Parameter A for alpha=.001
x0 <- 7.4 # Parameter x0 for alpha=.001
d <- 2.8 # Parameter d for alpha=.001
    }
    out.pow <- NULL # initialize vector
for(ncases in ncases){
    OR.ctrl.cas <- 1 / OR.cas.ctrl # 1. CALCULATE P1 FROM A PREDEFINED P0, AND A DESIRED OR
    OR <- OR.ctrl.cas
    bracket.pw <- p0 / (OR - OR*p0) # obtained after isolating p1 in OR equation [3].
    p1 <- bracket.pw / (1 + bracket.pw)
    Nh037 <- Nh^0.37 # 2. CALCULATE NSCALED
    num.n <- num.cases*((p1-p0)^2)
    den.n <- (p1*(1-p1) + p0*(1-p0))*Nh037
    Nscaled <- num.n/den.n
    num.power <- A - 100 # 3. CALCULATE POWER
    den.power <- 1 + exp((Nscaled - x0)/d)
    power <- 100 + (num.power/den.power) # The power I have to detect a given OR with my     data, at a given alpha
    }
OR <- OR.cas.ctrl
out.pow <- data.frame(num.cases, Nh, Nscaled, p0, OR, sig.level, power)
out.pow
} 

mydata <- f(ncases=seq(50,1000, by=50), 0.4, 2.25, 11, 0.05)
mydata

library(ggplot2)
print(ggplot(data = mydata, aes(num.cases, power)) +
theme_bw() +
theme(text=element_text(family="Helvetica", size=12)) +
labs(title = "Ad-hoc power for haplogroup") +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2", guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
xlab("number of cases/controls") +
ylab("power") +
scale_x_log10() +
geom_line(alpha=0.8, size=0.2) +
geom_point(aes(shape = factor(OR)), colour="black"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have `n.cases` named inconsistently I think. It's `n.cases` sometimes, and `ncases` other times. Is that a mistake?

Anyway, `output$mydata()` is incorrect. It isn't an output. It should be just:

```
mydata <- reactive(f(input$n.cases,
  input$p0,
  input$OR.cas.ctrl,
  input$Nh,
  input$sig.level))
```

And then when executing it in `output$powHap()` it should be:

```
output$powHap <- renderPlot(
{
   print(ggplot(data = mydata(), aes(ncases, power)) + 
     theme_bw() + 
     theme(text=element_text(family="Helvetica", size=12)) + 
     labs(title = "Ad-hoc power for haplogroup") +
     scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2", guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
     xlab("number of cases/controls") +
     ylab("power") +
     scale_x_log10() +
     geom_line(alpha=0.8, size=0.2) +
     geom_point(aes(shape = factor(OR)), colour="black"))
})
```

The important part there is that you need to do:

```
data = mydata()
```

rather than

```
data = output$mydata
```

Because `output$mydata` is a (reactive) function.

---

I would suggest reading [the documentation on how reactives work](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#reactivity-overview). The whole thing should make a lot more sense afterwards. +1 for a very reproducible example by the way. This is how all questions should be posted.

Comment: Thanks! It works just great. I have not programming background (other than R) and I messed up all when I started with **Shiny**. I will also review the inconsistencies in the *f()* function.

Comment: Thanks again! after this being solved, a new read of that tutorial will make things clearer for me.

Comment: I have just edited my post, changing n.cases for num.cases in the function f().